# Customizing Email Verification Notification

Tags: laravel

I have a project requirement whereby we wish to send the email validation messages from SendGrid. To this end, I've overridden the **sendEmailVerificationNotification** in **App\User**

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\SendGridEmailNotifications);
    }
```

And generated a notification class:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Log;

class SendGridEmailNotifications extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {


        /* Send via SendGrid. */

        //Array of variables for SendGrid.
        $payload = array();

        $this->callSendGridAPI('mail/send', 'POST', $payload);

        /*
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');

        */

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
```

My issues is that the process assumes a return of type MailMessage to be sent later via the MailChannel. However, if I remove the 'via' e.g.

```
public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Then the class is not run at all and nothing happens. If I leave the 'mail' in place, I hit an error in MailChannel as obviously not MailMessage is being returned here.

In short, how can I configure this notification to simply hit the SendGrid API and then quit? Can I define a 'null' or dead-end channel?

Thank you!

Comment: Someone created a [sendgrid notification channel](https://github.com/cuonggt/laravel-sendgrid-notification-channel) package, but I do not know if it works (currently only has 19 installs). You may want to try it out first, or if it doesn't work, you can use it as a basis to create your own notification channel.

Comment: Thank you Patricus, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution, you can create your own channel:

```
namespace App\Channels;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendGridChannel
{
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $message = $notification->toSendGrid($notifiable);

    }
}
```

And call it as so:

```
use App\Channels\SendGridChannel;

class SendGridEmailNotifications extends Notification
{

 public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [SendGridChannel::class];
    }

  public function toSendGrid($notifiable)
    {
      //As in opening question
    }

}
```